# Convert a string list input to a number list

Tags: python, list

I want to convert a string list input to a number list goes n python. Can ent one help?

I have done this

```
a=int(input())
```

But it is giving error

Comment: What are you typing in for the input?  What's the error?

Comment: The question says it's a "string list" so I assume it's multiple ints, but they don't say how the ints are separated.

Comment: Yeah I have seem to have misread the question, so I've deleted my comment